# Java Rest Endpoint Response Cleanup Actions

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring to create a Java rest endpoint, and would have some lengthy cleanup chores that need to be performed after each call to my endpoint. Is there a good way to return the response, and then perform the specific cleanup actions using data generated during the call?

For example:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public User getUser(
    @PathParam("id") Integer id) throws NotFoundException {
  final String logRequest = "User retrieval request for user " + id;
  logger.info(logRequest);
  User user = userService.getById(id);

  doMyChoresThatTakeALongTime(user); // how can I make this happen *AFTER* returning the reponse?

  logger.info(logRequest + " succeeded");
  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should create an another bean (service) and execute this method asynchronously. See [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async)

Edit: You will need to [enable it](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-enable-annotation-support) first, for example using `@EnableAsync`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for. Thanks!